# Laravel Eloquent get last pivot record within Model method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

As in the title, is it possible to achieve something like this?

```
class Sign extends Eloquent
{
   public function lastStatus()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class)
                  ->withPivot('timestamp')
                  ->orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
                  ->take(1);
   }
}
```

There is many-to-many relationship between `sign` and `status`, I've got pivot table `sign_status`. Every assignment in `sign_status` has its `timestamp`, so I can get information about the last status, but how to achieve this within Model method?

It is necessary to do it in this way, because then I will build a query like:

```
Gantry::whereHas('sign.lastStatus', function($q){...});
```

And i will filter by status which is an error to get gantries which at least one sign has error - but I need to search for that error in the last statuses of each sign.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `$this->hasMany(Status::class)`

Comment: sorry for my disunderstanding, I thought it should be `one-to-many` relationship in this case